# AngularFireFunctions httpCallable not updating after response

Tags: angular, angularfire2, rxjs-observables

Using an Observable from AngularFireFunctions' `httpsCallable`, the view never updates with the value even after the http request returns.

I have a simple component that uses AngularFireFunctions to make an httpCallable to a simple function. I can see the call being made in the browser's network inspector, and I have a `tap(x=>console.log(x))` on the observable which does indeed log the value returned from the function. However, `{personObservable | async | json}` **is null even after the observable has a value** (the console log from the tap triggers).

**Component:**

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-simple-test',
 template: '{{personObservable | async | json}}'
})
export class SimpleTestComponent implements OnInit {

    personObservable: Observable<any> = this.fireFunctions
            .httpsCallable('getPerson')({})
                .pipe(
                    tap(person => console.log(person))
                );

    constructor(
            private fireFunctions: AngularFireFunctions) { 
    }
...
```

**Firebase function:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const viewInvite = 
        functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {name: "test name"};
});
```

As expected, a page load causes an http request to the firebase function, and the console will contain `{name: "test name"}` indicating that the http request worked, tap was triggered, and the observable now has a value. **The page will still render "null".**

I've tried replacing the `httpsCallable(...)(...)` with a simple `of({name:"test"})`, and that worked fine.

Is there something special about the Observable that httpsCallable returns that prevents the view from using its value?

Comment: i am not familiar with angualarfire. But form the rxjs side, i can't find any error.
can you check in console if null is also logged, only the latest data returned will be rendered in view

Comment: I am having this exact same problem and doesn't make sense to me.Did you get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing this weird output, but I've identified two ( not ideal ) solutions for anyone struggling with it:

**1. Convert the observable toPromise() - and back to observable if you need it like that**

```
personPromise = personObservable.toPromise();
return from(personPromise);
```

**2. Call function via HTTP request.**